# Story where world is all about creating things using computer to gain enough "credits" to not be reprogrammed

Tags: story-identification

Looking for story in an anthology from 70's 80's.  where world is all about creating things using computer to gain enough "credits" to not be reprogrammed  You use credits by eating and rent  but dating is by sending a simulated you and you gain credits. Creation occurs by combining things such as 1/2 Bach + 1/4 Bob Dylan + 1/4 Elvis with a song about love and when people like it you get credits.

No one leaves the city but protagonist does and he gets transferred to galactic hub.

Thanks for helping with finding this story.